# Jest Testing - Unexpected token Error

Tags: reactjs, unit-testing, jestjs

I am constantly facing this error.

```
FAIL  src\__tests__\app-test.js
  ? Test suite failed to run
```

> C:/Work/Insurance POC/Front End/hip/login/src/__tests__/app-test.js: Unexpected token (105:28)

```
        104 | test('App should render', () => {
      > 105 |     const appTest = shallow(<h1>Welcome</h1>);
            |                             ^
        106 |     expect(appTest).toBeDefined();
        107 | })
        108 |

Test Suites: 1 failed, 1 total
Tests:       0 total
Snapshots:   0 total
Time:        7.3s
Ran all test suites.
```

The problem seems to be conversion into JSX. No matter what the element is there in shallow(), it throws the same 'Unexpected token' error. Please suggest some work-around or changes in configuration that could solve the issue.

What I have tried:

npm install babel-plugin-transform-react-jsx and including the plugin in .babelrc

Comment: Have you got `react` and `es2015` in your `.babelrc` file and is the `.babelrc` file in your root folder?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As discussed you needed to have the relevent presets in your `.babelrc` file:

```
{"presets": ["es2015", "react"]}
```

And ensure `.babelrc` file is in the root directory.

Comment: The issue was solved by moving the .babelrc file to the root directory. Please include that.